# Remove specific points in graph produced by R packages ggfortify/ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggfortify

The aim is to remove specific points in a graph produced by `ggfortify` and `ggplot2`.

Let's use the famous `iris` data set from package `ggfortify`:

```
library(ggfortify)
library(ggplot2)
df <- iris[c(1, 2, 3, 4)]
autoplot(prcomp(df))
autoplot(prcomp(df), data = iris, colour = 'Species', shape = FALSE, label.size = 3, frame=T)
```

[image: This is a PCA graph of the three iris species, separated by color and "frame." The points represented in each "frame" are numbered. These numbers are the focus of this question]

How do I remove numbers 23, 14, and 52 from the graph?

Comment: `ggplot` graphs data that you give it. If you don't want it plotting certain rows, don't give it those rows.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(ggfortify)
library(ggplot2)
df <- iris[c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)]
df <- df[-c(14,23,52),]
df2<-df[c(1,2,3,4)]
autoplot(prcomp(df2))
autoplot(prcomp(df2), data = df,
    colour = 'Species', shape = FALSE, label.size = 3, frame=T)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like those numbers are basically just row numbers. If thats the case you can make another table with only the rows you want and do everything else the same:

```
iris2 = iris[-c(14,23,52),]
```

Then just plug in substitute `iris2` everywhere in your code you currently use `iris`